# disable previous dates in jqerymobile dates

Tags: jquery-mobile

disable previous dates in jquerymobile dates  and I need to disable dates e.g. weekends and holidays on a jQueryMobile date picker similar to the jQuery. i want disable previous dates in jquerymobile.js please give the suggestion

Comment: Welcome to the Stackoverflow. Can you tell us what plugin do you use to add Dates functionality.

Comment: Because this is your first question we will not close it. Read [**this**](http://www.gajotres.net/how-to-ask-a-good-stackoverflow-question/) article if you want to find how to properly ask a question here. Then made changes accordingly.

Comment: i am using mobilejquery.js,i given <input type='date' id='getname' name='getname'/> in datepicker popup disable the previous dates.please help me

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are trying this date picker..[JQM Datepicker](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.0/datepicker/). You can find the options in that page with this link..[JQM Datepicker options](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/). I haven't tried this but JQM says this third party plugin supports their own Jquery datepicker options.

Comment: Thank You.but how can i reduce the width and height of the datepicker.